# What is this kind of instantiation called in Java?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, overriding, instantiation

This may be a very elementary question for Java, but I just can't recall it and have no clue how to search it online.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
     Thread.sleep(100);
   }
}
```

I'm used to initializing an object using constructors like `new OnClickListener(arg1, arg2, ...)`. In my own experience I've never override a method when constructing an object. I've only done it when extending a class. What is this kind of instantiation called in Java if there's any term for it? In what other cases should we use it?

Comment: The name is `Anonymous Classes` in Java. Now you can proceed with your research on this topic.

Comment: `OnClickListener` is definitely anonymous instantiation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an *anonymous* class. It's an implementation of the `OnClickListener` interface, but that implementation is unnamed. It's concise to write and the implementation is visible in the calling context (often useful for readability), but since it's an implementation in-place, you can't use it elsewhere.

Note also that it's an inner class and hence has a reference to its surrounding class.

See [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) for more info.

Re. the reference to a surrounding class. An inner class has an implicit reference to its outer class (you can see this if you attempt to serialise the inner class using, say, XStream. It'll pull the outer class along with it). If you have a variable in the outer class, you can reference it in the inner (provided it's a `final` variable, mind)

Comment: I'm not sure what "has a reference to its surrounding class" means. Could you please name a scenario where such a reference can be used?

Answer (score 3):

They are called anonymous classes.

Technically they are subclasses of the class being instantiated, and provide overridden method implementations.

They are useful when you want to provide an implementation without having to specifically declare a top level class.

They are Java's answer to closures.

Answer (score 2):

```
new OnClickListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    Thread.sleep(100);
  }
}
```

Both from the syntax and semantics perspective, this construct is a blend of **instantiation** and **class declaration**. In the same breath you specify which constructor of `OnClickListener` to call (interfaces are assumed to have the default constructor for this purpose) and provide the class body that belongs to the new subclass you are declaring. You are not giving a name to the subclass, that's why this construct is called an "anonymous class". With an anonymous class instantiation is tightly coupled to declaration and you can't instantiate this class from any other point in code except where it is declared.

There is a nearly identical construct in Java that you'll almost never see used in practice: a **local class**. It looks just like a regular class declaration, but it occurs **inside a method**, just like the anonymous class above. In this case the class is given a name and can be referred to and instantiated on several places, but all of them inside the method where it is declared.

In both cases you get the special feature not available to any other class, which is the ability to use the **local variables** declared in the method. This is odd at first because the local variable disappears when the method completes, but the reference to an instance of the local class goes on living. This is why these classes are called "closures": they are said to "close over" their local environment. They kind of "lift" the variable declarations and keep them as their instance variables.

Answer (score 1):

Just to give a bit of an example of how this could be used...

```
public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OutOfTheMain ootm = new OutOfTheMain();
    }
}

public interface SuperInner {
    String words = "hello";
    String getWords();
}

public class OutOfTheMain {
    OutOfTheMain() {
        testInnerStuff(new SuperInner() {
            @Override
            public String getWords() {
                return words + " world";
            }
        });
    }

    private void testInnerStuff(SuperInner sinner) {
        System.out.println(sinner.getWords());
    }
}
```

When ran, this would print...

```
hello world
```

You can override methods to add additional functionality and use this class later on at runtime.